# How to replace "-" with a space?

Tags: python

I'm making a hangman program, and I want it to be able to include phrases; however, when I input a phrase to be guessed, the output only dashes. For instance, when I put in "how are you"(input to be guessed), the output is "-----------". What i want the out put to be is "--- --- ---", as it makes it easier for the player to know that it is a phrase. I've tried a 'for' loop and 'if' statement to now avail, and would appreciate some help. Thanks!
*At the moment I'm trying replace. Also, if this is badly worded, let me know and I'll try rewriting it.

```
right = ""
guess=""
attempts = 6
tries = 0
space = " "

print("Hangman: guess letters until you can guess the word or phrase.")
print("In this game you get six tries.")

right_str = str(input("\nEnter your word: "))
right_str = right_str.lower()

#displays the proper amount of unknown spaces
right = right * len(right_str)

if space in right_str:
    right_str.find(space, i)
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is only part of the code. I can post the rest if that would make it easier

Comment: What is `i`? And `find` is pure afaik. It doesn't mutate anything.

Comment: I thought i was index

Comment: You haven't defined `i` anywhere though.

Comment: What i was trying to do with find was to find out where the values were and then figure out a way to replace them

Comment: i thoutht that i was a built in variable for index. I use it later in the code, and thats how it seems to work

Comment: Python probably has a `replace` method that replaces certain matches with another string.

Comment: No. `i` must be defined. It isn't a "built-in".

Comment: It does, however  I am trying to make a replace dashes at certain locations. so when i tried the replace method, it replaced all the dashes with spaces, instead of the just the ones that i needed. "How are you" at the moment is "-----------", and i want it to be "--- --- ---"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
guess=""
attempts = 6
tries = 0
space = " "

print("Hangman: guess letters until you can guess the word or phrase.")
print("In this game you get six tries.")

right_str = str(input("\nEnter your word: "))
right_str = right_str.lower()

output = ""
for c in right_str:
    if c != " ":
        output += "-"
    else:
        output += " "
print output
```